# cannot find artifact in Springsource Maven repository

Tags: spring, maven, osgi

I would like the upgrade to the latest version of Spring, but because I use Spring-DM which is now Eclipse Gemini Blueprint I need OSGi-ified Maven bundles.

The latest version I find in the Springsource repositories is 3.2.5.RELEASE. It can be downloaded from here:

http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/detail?name=org.springframework.core&version=3.2.5.RELEASE

However, when add this as a Maven dependency using the URL as in the FAQ, it cannot be found by Maven.
An older version 3.0.5.RELEASE CAN be found at the following address that Maven uses:

http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/org/springframework/org.springframework.core/3.0.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar

When I change 3.0.5 to 3.2.5 it can indeed not be found.

What is the problem? How come it is downloadable in the web version? Do I need to use another repository URL than http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release ?

Comment: I did find this post which was made on 2 eptember 2013, perhaps it's related. Note that version 3.2.5 was added to the repository in december 2013.
The repository is frozen but will remain accessible until at least 1 September 2014. See http://www.eclipse.org/ebr/ for information regarding the Eclipse Bundle Recipes project to which users of the SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository should transition.

Comment: Why not looking into [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.springframework%22%20AND%20a%3A%22spring-core%22).

Comment: Because it does not contain the OSGi version of the required jars. Anyway, I solved my problem by manually downloading the jar and deploying it to our private Maven repository.